# Static files not showing with nginx on django server

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have problem getting the static files with nginx.

This is the settings of my file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/app

```
location /static/ {
   alias /home/username/projects/website/static/;
}
```

And on my server I checked that my files acctually exist in this directory
***/home/username/projects/website/static/***

I see that files are being called in the wepage from ***http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/static/app/images/image.png***

This file exist on server in directory
***/home/username/projects/website/static/app/images/image.png***

My settings file have defines STATIC_ROOT like this

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/projects/website/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I'm really confused. Reading and searching for typos or mismatches. I really need a new set of eyes and pointers.

Comment: Did you do manage.py collectstatic ?
And try to delete trailing slash.

Comment: Yes. I guess the files wouldn't be in the directory I mention otherwise?

Comment: Can the nginx user actually access that directory?

Comment: check the directory permissions

Comment: Add error_log /var/log/nginx/website.error.log error; And  look what's there.

Comment: in _/etc/nginx/nginx.conf_ I have ***user username;***. And when I check permission on directory _/home/username/projects/website/static_  with _ls -ld_ it says ***drwxrwxr-x username***

Comment: @SergAnuke I checked the logs. They were empty.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I there another way to check permission than what I did in my comment above?

Comment: I think I found something interesting. After I done ***sudo service nginx stop*** I can still reach the webpage. Somehow it does not go through the nginx. Therefor not showing static or write to log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an answer to this. The issue is with your path

```
location /static/ {
   alias /home/username/projects/website/static/;
}
```

It should look like this

```
location /static {
   alias /home/username/projects/website;
}
```

I had similar issues so I created this [repository](https://github.com/NecoHorne/Django-Server-Setup) for a quick setup guide.